# Improve performance for query with nested LIMIT

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-performance, postgresql-11

I have two large tables in a Postgres 11.17 database: `procedure_result_sets` and `procedure_result`, where each set has many results.

I'm a stuck on about 0.3s when running this query.

Is there anything that I'm missing that could help speed this up?

```sql
with base_procedure_result_sets as (
    SELECT
       procedure_result_sets.id
    FROM
      procedure_results join procedure_result_sets on procedure_result_sets.id = procedure_results.procedure_result_set_id
    WHERE
      (
        procedure_run_started_at ::timestamp between now() - interval '10 days'
        and now() -- Dynamic date range scope.
      )
      and procedure_result_sets.procedure_id = ANY(VALUES (4), (5), (3))
    limit
      10000
 )

SELECT
  procedure_run_guid,
  json_object_agg(
    definition_name,
    case
      when (result_text is null) then result_number ::varchar
      else result_text
    end
  ) as s_result,
  min(created_at) as started_at
from
  procedure_results
where
procedure_results.procedure_definition_id = any (values (10), (9), (8), (7), (6), (5), (4), (3), (2), (1)) and
  procedure_result_set_id in (
    select
      procedure_result_set_id
    from
      procedure_results
    where
      procedure_results.procedure_definition_id = any (values (10), (9), (8), (7), (6), (5), (4), (3), (2), (1)) and 
       procedure_result_set_id in (
            select
              id
            from base_procedure_result_sets
          )
      
    limit
      200
  )
group by
  procedure_run_guid
order by started_at
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

```
"QUERY PLAN"
"Sort  (cost=170753.75..170758.66 rows=1965 width=56) (actual time=163.206..163.209 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (min(procedure_results.created_at))"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 30kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=4333 read=1359, temp written=826"
"  CTE base_procedure_result_sets"
"    ->  Limit  (cost=122002.86..167086.68 rows=72874 width=8) (actual time=87.537..144.026 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"          Buffers: shared hit=4169 read=1359, temp written=607"
"          ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=122002.86..167086.68 rows=72874 width=8) (actual time=87.537..140.300 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"                Hash Cond: (procedure_result_sets.procedure_id = ""*VALUES*_2"".column1)"
"                Buffers: shared hit=4169 read=1359, temp written=607"
"                ->  Hash Join  (cost=122002.78..166020.82 rows=97166 width=16) (actual time=87.517..133.295 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"                      Hash Cond: (procedure_results_2.procedure_result_set_id = procedure_result_sets.id)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=4169 read=1359, temp written=607"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on procedure_results procedure_results_2  (cost=0.00..30772.00 rows=1212200 width=8) (actual time=0.011..27.966 rows=199490 loops=1)"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=1711 read=1359"
"                      ->  Hash  (cost=119897.61..119897.61 rows=121054 width=16) (actual time=87.090..87.091 rows=121906 loops=1)"
"                            Buckets: 131072  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 3888kB"
"                            Buffers: shared hit=2458, temp written=267"
"                            ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on procedure_result_sets  (cost=2573.24..119897.61 rows=121054 width=16) (actual time=55.209..69.277 rows=121906 loops=1)"
"                                  Recheck Cond: ((procedure_run_started_at >= (now() - '10 days'::interval)) AND (procedure_run_started_at <= now()))"
"                                  Heap Blocks: exact=2122"
"                                  Buffers: shared hit=2458"
"                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on procedure_run_started_at_procedure_result_sets  (cost=0.00..2542.97 rows=121054 width=0) (actual time=54.912..54.912 rows=121906 loops=1)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((procedure_run_started_at >= (now() - '10 days'::interval)) AND (procedure_run_started_at <= now()))"
"                                        Buffers: shared hit=336"
"                ->  Hash  (cost=0.04..0.04 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=3 loops=1)"
"                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                      ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*_2""  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=3 loops=1)"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=3505.55..3559.58 rows=1965 width=56) (actual time=163.144..163.192 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: procedure_results.procedure_run_guid"
"        Buffers: shared hit=4333 read=1359, temp written=826"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=3505.55..3510.46 rows=1965 width=68) (actual time=163.131..163.136 rows=200 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: procedure_results.procedure_run_guid"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 40kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=4333 read=1359, temp written=826"
"              ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1646.95..3398.06 rows=1965 width=68) (actual time=163.035..163.091 rows=200 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (procedure_results.procedure_definition_id = ""*VALUES*"".column1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=4333 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1646.70..3370.27 rows=2162 width=76) (actual time=163.015..163.055 rows=220 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=4333 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1646.27..1648.27 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=163.008..163.010 rows=20 loops=1)"
"                                Group Key: procedure_results_1.procedure_result_set_id"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=4251 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                                ->  Limit  (cost=1640.34..1643.77 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=162.867..162.995 rows=200 loops=1)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=4251 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                                      ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1640.34..11084.80 rows=551000 width=8) (actual time=162.866..162.987 rows=200 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (procedure_results_1.procedure_definition_id = ""*VALUES*_1"".column1)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=4251 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1640.09..3363.66 rows=606100 width=16) (actual time=162.851..162.958 rows=220 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=4251 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                                                  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1639.66..1641.66 rows=200 width=8) (actual time=162.826..162.828 rows=20 loops=1)"
"                                                        Group Key: base_procedure_result_sets.id"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=4169 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                                                        ->  CTE Scan on base_procedure_result_sets  (cost=0.00..1457.48 rows=72874 width=8) (actual time=87.540..155.178 rows=100000 loops=1)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=4169 read=1359, temp written=826"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using index_procedure_results_on_procedure_result_set_id on procedure_results procedure_results_1  (cost=0.43..8.50 rows=11 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=11 loops=20)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (procedure_result_set_id = base_procedure_result_sets.id)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=82"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=0.12..0.12 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                                                  Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                                  ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*_1""  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Index Scan using index_procedure_results_on_procedure_result_set_id on procedure_results  (cost=0.43..8.50 rows=11 width=84) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=11 loops=20)"
"                                Index Cond: (procedure_result_set_id = procedure_results_1.procedure_result_set_id)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=82"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=0.12..0.12 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=10 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                          ->  Values Scan on ""*VALUES*""  (cost=0.00..0.12 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=10 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 1.015 ms"
"Execution Time: 164.893 ms"
```

I have the following indexes on the `procedure_result_sets` table:

```
"tablename" "indexname" "indexdef"
"procedure_result_sets" "index_procedure_result_sets_on_multi"  "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_result_sets_on_multi ON public.procedure_result_sets USING btree (procedure_run_guid)"
"procedure_result_sets" "index_procedure_result_sets_on_result" "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_result_sets_on_result ON public.procedure_result_sets USING gin (result)"
"procedure_result_sets" "index_procedure_result_sets_on_procedure_id"   "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_result_sets_on_procedure_id ON public.procedure_result_sets USING btree (procedure_id)"
"procedure_result_sets" "index_procedure_result_sets_on_procedure_id_and_starts_at" "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_result_sets_on_procedure_id_and_starts_at ON public.procedure_result_sets USING btree (procedure_run_started_at, procedure_id)"
"procedure_result_sets" "procedure_result_sets_pkey"    "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX procedure_result_sets_pkey ON public.procedure_result_sets USING btree (id)"
"procedure_result_sets" "procedure_run_started_at_procedure_result_sets"    "CREATE INDEX procedure_run_started_at_procedure_result_sets ON public.procedure_result_sets USING btree (procedure_run_started_at)"
```

And the following indexes on the `procedure_results` table:

```
"tablename" "indexname" "indexdef"
"procedure_results" "index_procedure_results_on_procedure_definition_id"    "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_results_on_procedure_definition_id ON public.procedure_results USING btree (procedure_definition_id)"
"procedure_results" "index_procedure_results_on_procedure_result_set_id"    "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_results_on_procedure_result_set_id ON public.procedure_results USING btree (procedure_result_set_id)"
"procedure_results" "index_procedure_results_on_procedure_id"   "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_results_on_procedure_id ON public.procedure_results USING btree (procedure_id)"
"procedure_results" "index_procedure_results_on_procedure_run_guid_and_result_number"   "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_results_on_procedure_run_guid_and_result_number ON public.procedure_results USING btree (procedure_run_guid, result_number) WHERE (result_number IS NOT NULL)"
"procedure_results" "index_procedure_results_on_procedure_run_guid_and_result_text" "CREATE INDEX index_procedure_results_on_procedure_run_guid_and_result_text ON public.procedure_results USING btree (procedure_run_guid, result_text) WHERE (result_text IS NOT NULL)"
"procedure_results" "procedure_results_pkey"    "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX procedure_results_pkey ON public.procedure_results USING btree (id)"
"procedure_results" "procedure_results_procedure_run_index" "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX procedure_results_procedure_run_index ON public.procedure_results USING btree (procedure_definition_id, procedure_run_guid)"
```

Comment: You say it takes 0.3 seconds, but the plan indicates it taking half that much.  Is that due to the real execution needing to move the data over the network, or just do to random fluctuations in the timings, or does it consistently get faster just due to caching effects of a repeat execution?

Comment: `= ANY(VALUES (4), (5), (3))` is an odd way to write that.  `IN (4,5,3)` might lead to be better index usage.

Comment: @jjanes It's version 11.17

Comment: The thing that stands out to me the most is the Bitmap Index Scan is weirdly slow, taking about 8 times longer than I would expect to read that number of tuple pointers from that number of pages.  What else is going on on the server at the time you run this?  Is the server just generally overloaded?  Is that index undergoing intense page locking for some reason?

Comment: Actual (relevant parts of) table definition would be instrumental. `CREATE TABLE` statements showing data types and constraints. What is the reason for first `LIMIT 1000` and then `LIMIT 200`? Seems arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb, you can probably untangle to just:

```
SELECT procedure_run_guid
     , json_object_agg(definition_name, result) AS s_result
     , min(created_at) AS started_at
FROM  (
   SELECT r.procedure_run_guid, r.definition_name, r.created_at
        , COALESCE(r.result_text, r.result_number::varchar) AS result
   FROM   procedure_results     r
   JOIN   procedure_result_sets rs ON rs.id = r.procedure_result_set_id
   WHERE  r.procedure_definition_id IN (10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
   AND    rs.procedure_id IN (4, 5, 3)
   AND    rs.procedure_run_started_at >= now() - interval '10 days'
   AND    rs.procedure_run_started_at <  now()  -- data type ???
   LIMIT  200
   ) sub
GROUP  BY procedure_run_guid
ORDER  BY started_at;
```

The result may differ from your original with first `LIMIT 10000` and then `LIMIT 200`. But that seems irrelevant since `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` produces arbitrary results anyway.

Then you just need indexes supporting selective `WHERE` clauses properly.
These existing indexes are basically good for this:

- `index_procedure_results_on_procedure_definition_id`
- `index_procedure_result_sets_on_procedure_id` + `procedure_run_started_at_procedure_result_sets`

This multicolumn index would likely be better than the cited two indexes for `procedure_result_sets`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.procedure_result_sets (procedure_id, procedure_run_started_at, id);
```

Depends on actual table definitions, how your filters can vary, and other undisclosed details.

---

Among other things, I rewrote this filter:

```
WHERE procedure_run_started_at::timestamp between now() - interval '10 days' and now()
```

The cast to `timestamp` makes no sense. `now()` returns `timestamptz`. And you should not have to cast the column at all, since that prevents indexes from being used.

Comment: if following one ok? `SELECT  procedure_run_guid ,json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT definition_name, coalesce(result_text,result_number) as result) AS x))  as s_result,min(created_at)
FROM    procedure_results       pr
JOIN    procedure_result_sets   prs
ON      prs.id = pr.procedure_result_set_id
WHERE   pr.procedure_definition_id      = IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
AND     prs.procedure_id                = IN (3,4,5)
AND     prs.procedure_run_started_at    >=  now() - interval '10 days' 
AND     prs.procedure_run_started_at    <   now() 
LIMIT   200 GROUP   BY  procedure_run_guid;`

Comment: @jian: Sorry, I don't understand. OK how? `= IN` is invalid in any case.

Comment: `SELECT  procedure_run_guid,
  json_agg((SELECT x FROM (SELECT definition_name, coalesce(result_text,result_number) as result) AS x))  as s_result
    ,min(created_at) 
FROM    procedure_results       pr JOIN    procedure_result_sets   prs 
ON      prs.id = pr.procedure_result_set_id 
WHERE   pr.procedure_definition_id       IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)  
AND     prs.procedure_id                    IN (3,4,5)
AND     prs.procedure_run_started_at    >=  now() - interval '10 days'  
AND     prs.procedure_run_started_at    <   now() 
LIMIT   200 GROUP   BY  procedure_run_guid;`  is this ok?

Comment: I rewrite it, based on your query, but I am not sure it's correct or not.

Comment: @jian: `LIMIT` must come after `GROUP BY`. Other than that: "correct" depends on your criteria. It's not exactly equivalent to mine in any case. Please start a new *question* if you have a question. Or write a new *answer*, if you have a new answer.